# Create a list of unique values from a column in multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have 3 data frames (df1, df2, df3) that explain the color, year and make of a car.  Each data frame has a column named "id".  Not all of the ids match in each data frame, but I want to create a list of unique ids across all three data frames.

```
 df1 looks like this:  

 id     color
 5A     black
 7T     green
 8Q     gold
 4D     white

 df2 looks like this:  

 id     make
 5A     BMW
 6N     Benz
 8Q     GM
 3G     Toyota

 df3 looks like this:  

 id     year
 5A     2003
 2B     2010
 8Q     1999
 4D     2007
```

Here's the code to make the 3 data frames:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(id=c("5A", "7T", "8Q", "4D"), color=c("black", "green", "gold", "white"))
 df2 <- data.frame(id=c("5A", "6N", "8Q", "3G"), make=c("BMW", "Benz", "GM", "Toyota"))
 df3 <- data.frame(id=c("5A", "2B", "8Q", "4D"), year=c(2003,2010,1999,2007))
```

I would like my final list to have the following values:

```
 id
 5A
 7T
 8Q
 4D
 6N
 3G
 2B
```

I tried using unique() but that only works for one vector?  Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this your ultimate goal or an intermediate step? If so, explaining the entire task may have other efficient answers..

Comment: @Sheila if one of the proposed answers is sufficient, please select it as the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
unique(c(df1$id, df2$id, df3$id))
```

works for numeric values.

```
unique(c(as.character(df1$id), as.character(df2$id), as.character(df3$id)))
```

returns the values as characters, and you could manipulate them back to factors if that's desired.

Comment: That was my first thought, too. However, when i run this, i get `[1] 2 3 4 1` do you get the desired output?

Comment: oh, good call. when I've done this in the past I've been working with numeric values.

Comment: Another question might be what the desired end goal is- if the hope is to eventually combine df1, df2, and df3, this step could be unnecessary in a larger dplyr::join-style approach

Answer (score 1):

This may be a way of doing it

```
lst <- list(df1, df2, df3)
unique(unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) unique(x[,1]))))

[1] 5A 7T 8Q 4D 6N 3G 2B
Levels: 4D 5A 7T 8Q 3G 6N 2B
```

Comment: If they were already in a list, this would be nice; not sure building a list is worth it. But also, you don't really need the inner unique and you can make things shorter with the '[[' function: `unique(unlist(lapply(lst, '[[', "id")))`